# iOS/coredata/swipe to delete: Why is following code not working?

Tags: ios, core-data, swipe-gesture

I am trying to get swipe to delete to work with core data using following code but it is not working. I realize that there are two approaches in following when only one is needed but I can't get it to work in any case. Would appreciate it if anyone can spot what is wrong.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
    //enables swipe to delete
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Remove the row from data model
 //first approach       
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete object from manageobjectcontext
            NSLog(@"should be deleting here");//this shows in log
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    //second approach
        // Delete the item
        Items *itemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", itemToDelete.name);//this also shows in log
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        [[self tableView] reloadData];

    }
```

Comment: What part is not working? The object is not being deleted or the table is not being updated?

Comment: Neither.  The table does not reflect any change afterward.  And when you close the simulator and re-open, the item is still there so it is clearly still in the underlying dbase (sqllite)

Comment: Is there an error when you save your context?

Comment: No.  Just doesn't get deleted.

Comment: It also seems to get the right row in the NS log output

Comment: Try - NSManagedObject *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj]; And save the context after changes, in the second approach this line missing.

Comment: Tried that but same result.  It is not deleting the item.

Answer (score 0):

Your two approaches do exactly the same thing (the only difference being a cast), so that won't help you.

The preferred way is to implement the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate. When you delete the object from the context, the delegate method `controller:didChangeObject:...` is called. The standard implementation (Xcode template: Master-Detail, check Core Data) will simply delete the row as expected (via `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`).

If you don't use the delegate methods (not recommended), you have to call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` yourself in `commitEditingStyle`.

Comment: There must be something wrong with how I am implementing nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate as it is not working. (I do have NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in header file.) I'll try to copy over code from master detail and see if that fixes things.